# Implementing tabs with Jquery .click() in Wordpress custom template

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tabs, show

I'm developing a web page in Wordpress [here](http://preview.jx6tbi4lxxrh33dig2ue7ze4otysc3disodyluk0mq60qkt9.box.codeanywhere.com/outfits/contrast-cowboy/) where I'm implementing tabs using Jquery.

When you click on a given thumbnail image in the image scroll bar it will open the corresponding tab in the section just below. This is working correctly.

The problem I'm experiencing is when you click on the actual tab names - you'll see that the content of the tab fails to load [Jquery .show() maybe isn't working?]. My javascript function is set to hide/show content based on the same class whether you click the image thumbnail or the tab name, so I'm not sure why one works but the other doesn't. Appreciate any advice you may have.

Below is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
<?php
if($post_objects){
    foreach($post_objects as $post_object){ ?>
    //product images and tabs
        jQuery(".outfit-selector-<?= $post_object->ID ?>").click(function(){
            jQuery(".wc-tab").hide();
            jQuery(".outfit-details-panel").hide();
            jQuery(".outfit-item-container").hide();
            jQuery(".product-details-pane-<?= $post_object->ID; ?>").show();
            jQuery(".outfit-item-container-<?= $post_object->ID; ?>").show();
            //tab active state
            jQuery('li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(".tab-<?= $post_object->ID; ?>").addClass('active');
        });
    <?php }
}
?>
    //outfit image and tab
    jQuery(".outfit-selector-whole").click(function(){
        jQuery(".wc-tab").hide();
        jQuery(".outfit-item-container").hide();
        jQuery(".outfit-details-panel").show();
        jQuery("#outfit-ms-whole").show();
        //tab active state
        jQuery('li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(".outfit-tab").addClass('active');
    });
}
</script>
```

Below is a simplified example of the HTML on page load:

```
<div class="outfit-images-pane">
    <div id="ms-selector" class="outfit-selector MagicScroll mcs-border">
        <div class='outfit-selector-whole outfit-selector-item'><img src='outfit-description.jpg' /></div>
        <div class='outfit-selector-231 outfit-selector-item'><img src='hats.jpg' /></div>
        <div class='outfit-selector-224 outfit-selector-item'><img src='casual-shirts.jpg' /></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outfit-details-pane">
    <div class='woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper'>
        <ul class='tabs wc-tabs'>
            <li class='outfit-selector-whole active description_tag outfit-tab'><a href='#outfit-description'>Outfit Description</a></li>
            <li class='outfit-selector-231 tab-231 description_tag'><a href='#Hats' class='product-tab-231'>Hats</a></li>
            <li class='outfit-selector-224 tab-224 description_tag'><a href='#CasualShirts' class='product-tab-224'>Casual Shirts</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class='outfit-details-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description panel entry-content wc-tab'>
            <div class='post_content'>
                <h3>Outfit Description</h3>
                <p>Tab content goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='product-details-pane-231 woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description panel entry-content wc-tab' style='display:none;'>
            <div class='post-content'>
                <h3><a href='url'>Tab Title</a></h3>
                <span class="amount"><span class="currencySymbol">&#36;</span>0.00</span>
                <p>Tab content goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='product-details-pane-224 woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--description panel entry-content wc-tab' style='display:none;'>
            <div class='post-content'>
                <h3><a href='url'>Tab Title</a></h3>
                <span class="amount"><span class="currencySymbol">&#36;</span>0.00</span>
                <p>Sold at: Store</p>
                <p>Tab content goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
<?php
if($post_objects){
    foreach($post_objects as $post_object){ ?>
    //product images and tabs
        jQuery(".outfit-selector-<?= $post_object->ID ?>").click(function(e){
            jQuery(".wc-tab").hide();
            jQuery(".outfit-details-panel").hide();
            jQuery(".outfit-item-container").hide();
            jQuery(".product-details-pane-<?= $post_object->ID; ?>").show();
            jQuery(".outfit-item-container-<?= $post_object->ID; ?>").show();
            //tab active state
            jQuery('li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(".tab-<?= $post_object->ID; ?>").addClass('active');
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();  // stopping the event propagation
        });
    <?php }
}
?>
    //outfit image and tab
    jQuery(".outfit-selector-whole").click(function(e){
        jQuery(".wc-tab").hide();
        jQuery(".outfit-item-container").hide();
        jQuery(".outfit-details-panel").show();
        jQuery("#outfit-ms-whole").show();
        //tab active state
        jQuery('li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(".outfit-tab").addClass('active');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();  // stopping the event propagation
    });
}
</script>
```

We are using [e.stopImmediatePropagation();](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to stop the event propagation to its parent. I hope it will work for you.